# Which Kotlin Coroutine data source (Channel, Flow,...) to use?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writting a messaging app (like whatsapp,...) for Android and I'm currently lost what is the best primitive to use from a lot of stuff released with latest coroutines. Would be grateful for some advice what to use (Channel, Actor, Flow, ChannelFlow,...) for queue implementation described in point 3 and 4.
My flow is like that:

1. User send a message
2. Message is stored to DB (Room). So if app is killed message is not lost.
3. Message is also offered to queue. What to use here (Actor, Channel, Flow, ChannelFlow)? This queue should be alive as long an app is alive or an exception described in point 5.

   3.a: I wish if could be possible to just save to DB and Flow from Room would requery stuff when queue is empty for sending but I don't know if that is possible, because for every insert/update/delete, query would be triggered and I would receive all messages again which are already in queue...
4. What do I need on the other side of the queue to get message from it and execute suspend function which will send message?
5. How to shutdown queue and recreate it in case of logout and login again? I guess CoroutineScope on which coroutine is running should be canceled and recreated again, right?

[image: Flow diagram]

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why did you need `channelFlow`?

Comment: It was just a question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd suggest adding an enum state to the `MessageEntity` (with states of `QUEUED`, `SENDING`, `SENT` or something similar)

Then I'd go with the following unidirectional flow, while considering your DB the SSO (Single Source of Truth):

User sends the message -> Insert message -> Room emits new Flow of items -> Trigger send request for `QUEUED` items -> Update state of messages

Flow has a nice api for filtering out only emissions which you need on your upper levels

Comment: Thanks. Was thinking about that solution also.